# box-shadow for table elements not working properly when used with sticky/relative positioning

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to provide a `box-shadow` for the first column of a table and along with that I am also using `position: sticky; left: 0` for the first column elements. `box-shadow` is appearing in Firefox but not in Chrome, I have already tried with a different z-index but nothing seems to work in Chrome.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: skyblue;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Column 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the code, I am using `sticky` but I have also tried with `relative` positioning too, but the result is same.

#### Firefox:

[image]

#### Chrome:

[image]

Comment: You can try `border-collapse:separate;`.

Comment: this does seem to work; but what if I want the border's to collapse? and can you explain why this doesn't work in chrome but in firefox

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation for why the box-shadow is not rendered on sticky boxes in Chromium browsers. However, it does work with  `filter: drop-shadow()`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr td:first-child{
  position: sticky;
  left:0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: skyblue;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Column 1</div></td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Adding filter is working!! But I am also trying to understand why box-shadow is not working in chrome

Comment: the easy and short answer is, that HTML5 unlike HTML4 and CSS3 is not officially specified by a certified institution as the W3C.  HTML5 and CSS3 were developed on recommendations by WHATWG which also technically only specifies recommendations. As such it is up to the browser vendors to decide if they want to implement something and how they want to implement it. As a side fact the main reason why emails require HTML4.